# stack overflow vs segfault

Tags: c++, gdb, segmentation-fault, stack-overflow

I was having a very weird segfault that I eventually fixed today. It seems the problem was I was allocating a very large array on stack and that was causing the problem.

My question is, do you always get a SEGV signal on stack overflow? Is there any special signal that could alert there is a stack overflow problem?

I'm using g++ along with gdb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "signal" in the sense of Unix signals is apparently SEGV.  :)  If you mean signal like using a diagnostic tool that will tell you when something bad is happening, you could try valgrind, but really, your system just told you.  And knowing at compile time whether the stack will be overflowed is not possible, partly because the stack size limit is a runtime parameter, and besides I imagine if you knew what it would be a priori, you'd still be stuck with something like the Halting Problem.

Comment: I see. Problem is this was only happing at very large problem size which is almost impossible to treat with valgrind. At smaller problem sizes, valgrind was telling me nothing and the code was working just fine! GDB was also producing a segfault and indicating a line that had nothing to do with it ... I was hoping gdb could catch the stack overflkow and produce a more meaningful error!

Comment: Actually, with `gcc`, it's conservatively possible using the `-Wframe-larger-than=len` flag. See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

Comment: @DavidTitarenco: The OP can tell us better, but I'm not sure that option will help in this case, because it seems to be a problem that occurs when some runtime conditions are met, such as a large data size which presumably either results in large stack depth or a large array allocated in "alloca" style.